# Changes in my Admin Panel don't always take effect

Tags: ee2, admin, caching

We've got two separate sites running with EE and on each we have the same problem:
Sometimes changes made in the admin panel just don't take effect. An example which happens frequently:

1. Login as super user (user A)
2. Move user B from admin group to a group unable to access admin panel
3. View member groups page, see that B doesn't have access
4. Refresh page, everything still looks good
5. Logout/Login as A again, and B's permissions are back to enabled

It's getting pretty frustrating. Sometimes we have to refresh pages in the admin panel to get updates, sometimes changes we submit get the little checkmark but don't actually do anything - sometimes changes go live for a few hours and then revert back to how they were. It's like there's some bizarre caching going on in the admin panel but that doesn't even make sense.

This recently started on our AWS server, but the switch to AWS also coincided with the launch of these EE sites, so we're not sure if they're related. Our IT guys have stated they've combed the server configurations and it's nothing on the server end, but I'm open to ideas.